# "off colour" and "out of sorts" in British English

Tags: idioms, british-english

I am wondering whether "off colour" and "out of sorts" are completely interchangeable idioms in British English, and if not, what the difference is.

> John {looks/feels} a bit {off colour/out of sorts} today.

An Australian co-worker of mine told me it could mean "upset", but I find his explanation contrary to dictionary definition.

Comment: A dictionary would agree with you; however be aware that "off-color" means something different in American English:  "(of remarks, jokes, etc.) rude or offensive to some people, sexual or suggestive"

Comment: Several dictionaries include this phrase, with NAmE and BrE meanings clearly differentiated.

Answer (score 4):

In your usage

> off colour
>   John **looks** a bit off colour.

may have more to do with John's appearance, whereas

> out of sorts
>   John **is** out of sorts today.

would be more about his physical, mental, or emotional *state*, and not necessarily his appearance, but his appearance may be effected by his *state*.  "**Out of sorts**" usually has more of a *manic* / *active* feel whereas "**off colour**" would be more subdued.

However, you might hear

> John **looks a bit out of sorts** today, he's under a lot of stress.
>   John is a bit manic today, he's under a lot of stress.*
>
> John **feels a bit off colour** today, he has a slight cold.
>   *John's not feeling well, he has a slight cold.*

But both would indicate John is somehow not well.

Comment: Yes, but noting [this definition](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/out+of+sorts) *(not feeling well; **grumpy** and **irritable**)* I think "out of sorts" could just as well be primarily a reference to one's ***mental*** state (which doesn't *always* have to be directly caused by a problem with one's internal *physical* state, health, whatever).

Comment: @FumbleFingers have updated answer, I was thinking all of that as "physical" as opposed to "appearance"

Comment: I absolutely agree that *on average*, "off colour" is more likely to be about appearance, where "out of sorts" is more to do with *physical, mental, or emotional **state***. I don't know if that could be supported by usage stats for how often each occurs after ***feel*** as opposed to ***look***, but that would certainly be my expectation.

Answer (score 2):

> **Off colour** *adjective* [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/off_colour)
>
> 1 (British) Slightly unwell.
>   ‘I'm feeling a bit off colour’
>
> 2 Slightly indecent or obscene.
>   ‘off-colour jokes’
>
> **Out of sorts** *phrase* [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/out_of_sorts)
>
> 1 Slightly unwell.
>   ‘she's been feeling nauseous and generally out of sorts’
>
> 1.1 In low spirits; irritable.
>   ‘the trying events of the day had put him out of sorts’

The phrases are interchangeable in some contexts, as the first definitions above indicate. There are, however, situations where they aren't - such as situations involving definition 2 of *off colour*. Also, the *irritable* sense of *out of sorts* also doesn't translate well to *off colour*.

In practice, *off colour* is used to describe someone else, whereas *out of sorts* might be used by both the observer and by the one who is unwell. For example, if Bob was unwell, he might say that he was (or felt) out of sorts. It would be odd to hear him say that he (himself) was (or felt) off colour.

Answer (score 2):

There is no *exact definition* of

> **off colour**

it's one of those terms you get to know through enough usage. It merely means one is not *feeling well*. It could be the flu, it could be hay fever, but whatever it is, it is not fatal.  You can also be said to be/feel off colour when you are *hung over*.

You are right to think it is not really related to **upset**.  **Off colour** is usually more *physical* than *emotional*.

[image]

Comment: Peter please don't paste pictures of text in answers. The text in that picture isn't searchable. Surely you can find a dictionary definition to link to to support your answer. If not, you should at least describe where this image came from and fill out that "enter image description" part for folks using screen readers or text only browsers.